# DBA Stackexchange bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Looked in the help section to figure out where to post a bug report, it's minor but still.

The candle icon for "Achievements" has a bug at least for my account where there is +12 rep for Stack Overflow and a +2 rep for DBA though no text to the right like all the other rows.

When I go to Stack Overflow the bug appears the same way (first Stack Overflow then DBA).

It would be great if someone could please update the help section with directions on where to file a bug report.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It might be a good idea to illustrate the problem with a screenshot. So far it looks like you might be referring to the aggregate row, which indeed doesn't (nor is supposed to) have any text, only site icons and corresponding rep change amounts.

Comment: @AndriyM Done, good idea, just in a rush being productive. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bug here, that is a summary row showing a metric for each site with relevant data, and it has nothing to do with individual posts. Here is what mine looks like:

> [image]

In general, issues that affect multiple sites and not just this one should be raised here (after searching of course):

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/